# How to create a gcs bucket without selecting a project

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a gcs bucket using this link: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets, but when I click on "Open The Cloud Storage Browser", it asks me to select a project. I want the bucket content to be publicly available. Any idea how can I do that? I dont want my bucket to be associated with a project, instead it should be in a global namespace. TIA.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a bucket requires specifying a project.
Making the bucket content publicly accessible is a separate matter - you can set ACLs or IAM policies on the bucket that grant public access.